# Hidden <td> value assign to js variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, json

I want to assign a hidden `td` value to a `id` javascript variable. I used `id = $(e.target).closest('tr').find('.orderid').val()` line to do this. but it not works. Please help me to solve this.

```
<tr>
  <td class="orderid" style="display:none;" value="{{this.id}}"/>{{this.id}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I think the below answers should work if you retrieved id correctly. maybe the problem is your json object, can you show me your json object that you want to retrieve?

Answer (score 0):

On this line ***value*** attribute is not valid for a ***td*** element :

```
<td class="orderid" style="display:none;" value="{{this.id}}"/>{{this.id}}</td>
```

Should use this (if i understand correctly) :

```
<td class="orderid" style="display:none;" id="{{this.id}}"/>{{this.id}}</td>
```

Then if you need to retrieve this id :

```
id = $(e.target).closest('tr').find('.orderid').attr('id');
```

Comment: this not works. even this not show the id in the JSON object. Why I can't save id (come from DB) to a JSON object.